# Stripe API - search for customer by email with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I just created a new stripe test product. I also have a webhook.php endpoint on my server to be notified that a Checkout session was complete. However, the `checkout.session` object that I recieve shows the `customer` property as `null`. So in my webhook.php I am trying to look it up by email but not having any success:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_key'
);
$email = 'joe@example.com';
$query = $stripe->customers->search([
  'query' => 'email:'.$email,
]); 

echo json_encode($query);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also curious if anyone knows why the `customer` property is null. Seems like the customer id would be a very important thing to get in the webhook

Answer (score 1):

Check this: [customer-email-search](https://stripe.com/docs/search#customers-email-search)

Probably the problem resides in adding \'$email\'

try this:

```
$email = 'joe@example.com';
$query = $stripe->customers->search([
  'query' => 'email:\''.$email .'\'',
]);
```

Comment: Here is the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Stripe\StripeClient" not found in /var/www/`

Comment: Interesting that something like this does work: `$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);`

Comment: check the verion that you have downloaded